# Fix Magento redirect to live site in local machine

Tags: upgrade, redirect, domain

I have followed these steps in order to get my live Magento working on my local machine:

1. Rsynced all files to my local machine
2. Cleared all cached on live site
3. Copied the db into my local mysql
4. Changed the values in `core_config_data` under `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to the new url (I've created a vhost on my local machine so my website address is www.mymagento.lc)
5. Deleted all files in `var/cache` and `var/session`
6. Changed the db details in `app/etc/local.xml`
7. Deleted all mentions to my old url in `.htaccess` file (after I made a backup of it)

I've done all that and every time I try to access Magento on my local machine I get redirected to my the live url.

What am I missing?

PS: When I tried to re-index running this command from `mysite/shell` `php indexer.php --reindexall` I get an error saying that Mage can't connect to the db using the credentials (which is slightly different than the ones in `app/etc/local.xml`

My Magento version is 1.4 (hence I'm moving it to my local machine to update it) and I run PHP projects on my local machine using the techniques described above without issues.

Comment: Does this Magento installation use Redis? If yes - try flushing it's cache too. And don't forget to check write permissions for cache holder in local Magento installation.

Comment: As far as I know this installation doesn't use Redis. Also, I've changed all files permission to `_www:_www` which is the apache user under OS X.

Comment: Double check the permission of magentoRoot/var/cache (check your php temp folder /tmp to see if there are any mage- files). Try deleting cached again, clearing/deleting cache should be the last thing you do.

Comment: I've done all that. All seems ok. No mage files in `/tmp`. I've also managed to re-index and restarted my machine and yet I still get redirected. I'm at my wit's end now... Any more suggestions?

Comment: Are there session and cache file generated in the var folder? When you rename the local.xml to local.bak does the install process kick off?

Comment: There are many different base URL values. Try searching core config data for the main components of your production URL and replace all instances, then clear cache and try again

Answer (score 2):

Because you have stated that you are getting a db connection error when trying to re-index at the command line it sounds like your local.xml is not correct.

1) You should rename your local.xml to something other than anything dot xml (like local.bak) and let the install process run. This will ensure you have a working database.

2) You should install Magerun which will allow you to diagnose issues from the command line much easier.

3) You can also try to connect to your database from your command line which will ensure that you can actually connect to your database.

4) On your local machine for testing you can decrease permissions to ensure that part of your problem is not permission related.

Comment: I have done the above. The problem now is just the redirect. I did manage to re-index and have lowered folder/files permissions (0777 on local dev machine) and yet the problem persists. I'm thinking if its possible to export the whole of magento (orders, settings, products, etc) into a new install?

Comment: You site will come up on a fresh version of Magento and your database. Why don't you checkout a new version of Magento and point it at your database and see if you get a redirect